# What's wrong with this recursion program

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to reverse a string using recursion but it's not working.
What's the mistake?..
It's showing some output "tset a ♠♣♦♥☻☺" for test case "this is a test"

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

void rec(char [],int,int);

void main()
{
  char ch[50];int j,i=0;
  printf("Enter the string: ");
  gets(ch);
  j=strlen(ch)-1;
  rec(ch,i,j);
  puts(ch);
}

void rec(char ch[],int i,int j)
{
  char t;
  if(i>=j)  return;
  t=ch[i];
  ch[i]=ch[j];
  ch[j]=i;
  rec(ch,++i,--j);
}
```

Comment: `ch[j]=i;` should be `ch[j]=t;`

Comment: stupid mistake..got it now., thanks..

Comment: Side note: Change `rec(ch,++i,--j)` to `rec(ch,i+1,j-1)`. There is no point in changing the values of those variables, since they are not used after that line).

Answer (score 1):

```
ch[j]=i;
```

You are assigning an integer to character which is not what you want.
You are storing the value in `t` so

```
ch[j] = t;
```

is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
ch[j]=i;
```

to

```
ch[j]= t;
```

Note that **no need to null terminate the string explicitly**. `strlen` gives th length the string excluding the `\0` character. You are passing `strlen(ch)-1` to your function it means it will start reversing the characters from the character just before `\0`. So, after the reversal the string will be null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
ch[j]=i;
```

you are using `i` instead of `t`

The function could be written simpler with only two parameters. For example

```
void rec( char s[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        char c = s[0];
        s[0] = s[n-1];
        s[n-1] = c;

        rec( s + 1, n - 2 );
    }
}
```

and called like

```
rec( ch, strlen( ch ) );
```

Now try to write the function with only one parameter: `char s[]`:)